# How to make the header of a JTable transparent

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to create a JTable that is transparent. The table itself does not impose that much of a problem, I have implemented the TableModel and a TableCellRenderer and set setOpaque(false) on the JTable, the enclosing JScrollPane and the ViewPort of the JScrollPane.

The table now correctly draws headers as it lies in a JScrollPane, so I set my own TableCellRenderer for rendering the header using `getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new TaskTableHeaderRenderer());`. I want this to be transparent as well, just with text using a JLabel. But try as I might, I can't get it. The Renderer surely provides a transparent component (I even tried to use just a JPanel with setOpaque(false) on it) and I even tried setOpaque(false) on the JTableHeader and setting a transparent background color for all components in question. Nothing seems to help.

The LookAndFeel I am using is the PlasticXPLookAndFeel by JGoodies but I tried Metal and Windows Look & Feel implementations to no avail as well. Furthermore debugging indicates that the PlasticXPLookAndFeel uses the BasicTableHeaderUI without subclassing it.

So how can I achieve transparent table headers?

Answer (score 3):

```
Table.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
Table.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0.6f));
Table.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first create an cellRenderer

```
public class OpaqueHeader extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object ob,
            boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
        JLabel t = new JLabel(ob.toString());
        t.setOpaque(false);
        t.setForeground(Color.black);
        return t;
    }
}
```

and after in your JTable object

```
table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new OpaqueHeader());
```

Comment: well, as actually mentioned in the question, I already to so, but it won't help. I have updated the question to mention the fact more directly. Have you verified your solution?

Comment: this will remove some useful features of the table header such as rendering the ordering icons

Answer (score -1):

maybe override paintBackground() and make it not call super.paintBackground()?

Comment: Um, which "paintBackground" method are you talking about? I have checked the whole inheritance tree but none of the classes seems to have a method with that name.

Comment: basically u have 3 methods: paintBorder(), paintComponent(), and paintChildren(). [sorry about the paintBackground(), memory mis-serves me] try playing with paintComponent / paintBorder of the component representing the table header...